# Will a Testflight app's data be lost when users update to first App Store version?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

We have an app currently in Testflight that uses CoreData. When we launch v1.0 in the App Store, will the existing users' data be preserved or wiped?

The bundle ID will remain the same, so in theory it should just be like a regular update. There should be no Core Data migration issues either.

I can't believe I don't know the answer to this, but I'm being asked by a client and I have no way to currently test it. It's also proving surprisingly hard to find a definitive, up-to-date answer anywhere.

Comment: TestFlight is really just a mechanism to install a not-yet-published app (as well as providing an interface for testing notes and feedback). From the device's standpoint, installing the then-published app is no different than updating an existing app to a new version. The existing user's data will be preserved.

Comment: I believe it will be preserved, since the bundle ID will match, and most probably there is no flag that the app was installed from TestFlight or from the AppStore. Both versions use the same certificates, and the data should be preserved. NSUserDefaults and other data are definitely preserved. Hadn't tested with Core Data though.